# How to copy file to root "dist/" folder with VueJS?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I need to copy some files to the `dist` folder when running `npm run build` on a VueJS instance, but I don't know how to do it.

The file would be things like `sitemap.xml`, `robots.txt` and some other needed configuration files.

I can eventually create a new folder, either under `static/` or anywhere else, and say "copy these files in the /dist/ folder once created".

Is it possible?

Update: I'm using Webpack to generate the dist folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Vue make this problem special.

You can try this copy plugin for webpack

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin

It can copy files from anywhere to anywhere

Answer (score 11):

If you are using vue-cli, any file in the 'public' folder will be copied to your 'dist' folder.

See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there is no `webpack.config.js` file. All webpack configurations are managed by `quasar-cli` itself.

While it provides a `quasar.conf.js` file where we can extend webpack configrations as well.

I solved the same issue by following these steps (in `quasar.conf.js`):

`const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')`

Then inside build configurations:

`extendWebpack (cfg) {
   cfg.plugins.push( 
      new CopyWebpackPlugin(
          [{ context: '${__dirname}/src/root', from: '*.*' }]
       ) 
    );
}`

It does copies all files from `src/root` to the `dist/` during build command.

[This issue was really helpful to resolve it.](https://github.com/developit/preact-cli/issues/436)

Answer (score 1):

My working version:

```
extendWebpack(cfg, {isServer, isClient}) {
    cfg.plugins.push(
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
          {
            from: './src/root/*',
            to: './',
            flatten: true,
          }],
      )
    );
  }
```